# CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted IndexBlock 298298 found in cache '/Users/macuser/.gradle/caches/journal-1/file-access.bin'

Tags: android

My android projects runs and my app works but I keep getting these errors. 
Can anyone explain what is happening and how I can solve it?

> org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted IndexBlock 298298 found in cache '/Users/macuser/.gradle/caches/journal-1/file-access.bin'. 
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted IndexBlock 272355 found in cache '/Users/macuser/.gradle/caches/journal-1/file-access.bin'.
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted IndexBlock 256346 found in cache '/Users/macuser/.gradle/caches/journal-1/file-access.bin'.
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted IndexBlock 285739 found in cache '/Users/macuser/.gradle/caches/journal-1/file-access.bin'.
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted IndexBlock 272355 found in cache '/Users/macuser/.gradle/caches/journal-1/file-access.bin'.
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted IndexBlock 298298 found in cache '/Users/macuser/.gradle/caches/journal-1/file-access.bin'.
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted IndexBlock 272355 found in cache '/Users/macuser/.gradle/caches/journal-1/file-access.bin'.
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted IndexBlock 256346 found in cache '/Users/macuser/.gradle/caches/journal-1/file-access.bin'.
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted IndexBlock 272355 found in cache '/Users/macuser/.gradle/caches/journal-1/file-access.bin'.
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted IndexBlock 256346 found in cache '/Users/macuser/.gradle/caches/journal-1/file-access.bin'.
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted IndexBlock 298298 found in cache '/Users/macuser/.gradle/caches/journal-1/file-access.bin'.
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted IndexBlock 256346 found in cache '/Users/macuser/.gradle/caches/journal-1/file-access.bin'.
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted IndexBlock 298298 found in cache '/Users/macuser/.gradle/caches/journal-1/file-access.bin'.
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted IndexBlock 238437 found in cache '/Users/macuser/.gradle/caches/journal-1/file-access.bin'.
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted IndexBlock 298298 found in cache '/Users/macuser/.gradle/caches/journal-1/file-access.bin'.

Comment: Were you running Canary version of Android Studio?

Comment: What v of canary is this happening on

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I had the same issue on a mac as well.

1. Open your /Users/macuser/ folder
2. Press CMD + SHIFT + . (dot/period) to view hidden folders
3. DELETE .gradle folder
4. Restart Android Studio

This will cause Android Studio to rebuild and re-download your .gradle folder fixing your corrupt files in the process.

NOTE* I'm looking for experienced programmers to let us know if this is safe / correct to do so! It worked for me with no errors but i'm new to this so a second opinion would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this is safe. It has no adverse effects since the file regenerates.

Comment: If you've stored any global constants inside `./gradle/gradle.properties`, you'll lose them.

Comment: My `.gradle` folder was so huge, it said it would take over 1 day to delete it!... So I canceled, then went into `C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\wrapper\dists` and deleted all the folders in there. That was much faster, and also did the trick! 

Comment: Thank you! I did this exactly, but without the restart of AS at the end and was still getting an error. Deleted the folder again, restarted AS, and everything worked.

Answer (score 8):

Best and Easiest Way is

1. Click on android studio menu button "File"
2. Click on "Invalidate Cache and Restart" Button
3. A popup box will open and click on "Invalidate and Restart"
4. Android Studio Invalidate Caches and Restart Again
5. Boom Your Problem is Solved.

Comment: Folder is open in another program. I am unable to delete

Answer (score 2):

I'm on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) and I got this error also.
I had to:

1. go to ~/.gradle/caches/journal-1
2. delete all the files
3. close Android Studio

Open Android Studio and everything is fixed again.
You have to restart Android Studio for the fix. it must store those files in memory or something.

Comment: wokerd on Mac also

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows and getting the same error try this.

1. delete file-access.bin in path C:\Users(User).gradle\caches\journal-1.
2. Restart android studio
3. Rebuild project

Answer (score 1):

**In Windows follow these steps**

1. C:\Users\user .gradle\caches\journal-1 --> delete all files
2. Restart Android studio.
3. Rebuild your project

Happy coding !

Comment: Folder is open in another program. I am unable to delete

Comment: Try after terminate your program in task manger or try after restart

Answer (score 1):

Just deleted the .gradle folder inside the project folder and restarted android studio worked fine in my case.

**Note**:  if you don't have a system-wide installation of gradle, the .gradle folder will not be able to be rebuilt after deletion. -- see comments for details.

Comment: This breaks the gradle wrapper. Please provide a means to restore this if this is a legitimate solution.

Comment: I'm not taking about the gradle folder, but the .gradle folder. How will it break the gradle wrapper I wonder .. ?

Comment: It seems that if you don't have a system-wide installation of gradle, the `.gradle` folder will not be able to be rebuilt after deletion. This `.gradle` folder appears to be essential to the operation of the wrapper, and if you remove it, the wrapper will not be able to rebuild itself. Thus, it breaks the wrapper. You can fix/rebuild the wrapper, but only if your system has gradle installed; this is not the default for many sprouting Android devs. You should include a caveat on this at the very least.

Comment: .gradle/ is commonly added in gitignore, So I thought it must be generated for new checkouts. I'll add your comment as caution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

after deleting the journal1 file in your .gradle folder open android studio to confirm if your flutter and dart is installed if not re-install it

Comment: this apply for flutter developers only

Answer (score 0):

**In Windows**
**There are two ways:**

***First way:***

-C:\Users.gradle\caches\journal-1
Delete all the files

-Restart Android studio.

-Rebuild your project

***Second way:***

-Go to file
click on --> Invalid Cache and Restart

Enter and finish

your Android studio will restart by it's own
Rebuild the project

This will work 100%

***#HappyCoding***

Answer (score 0):

In Windows There are two ways but this one worked for me.. hope it works out for you

First way:

-C:\Users.gradle\caches\journal-1 Delete all the files

-Restart Android studio.

-Rebuild your project

Answer (score -1):

open a terminal in android studio and type this command and rebuild your project it will 100% work

```
rm -R .gradle
```

Comment: you need to `cd` into the directory first, and to avoid prompts always rimraf

Answer (score -2):

try this:
Start with your original error message
"'/Users/macuser/.gradle/caches/journal-1/file-access.bin"
Shut down Android and restart your computer . Navigate to the location of the problem file.... 
relabel your "file-access.bin" to "file-accessOLD.bin"
restart Android and run your app.
Android will recreate the file and the corruption should disappear. 
[this is what the file folder looks like after the process completes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1WVf.png)