# Android Studio problem after adding any code

Tags: android, android-studio

I am facing the issue that when I create an project with empty activity, it works fine but as soon I add any code to activity it gives following error:

**> Caused by: org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted IndexBlock 637426 found in cache 'U:\Computer SCI\Semester_6\Mobile Application And Development\LABS\Project Fitness\caches\journal-1\file-access.bin'.**                                                           Here are my gradle files:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        //maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        mavenCentral()

    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}    

                                                                                             **File 2**                                                                                      

    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.imrankhan.fitness1"
        minSdk 22
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted IndexBlock 298298 found in cache '/Users/macuser/.gradle/caches/journal-1/file-access.bin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55801823/corruptedcacheexception-corrupted-indexblock-298298-found-in-cache-users-macu)

Comment: No, I tried all of the solutions but nothing worked! Still getting error